# Dynamic SQL Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need a suggestion for this.

We have common stored procedure,it will run across all the database in that server. Perviouly we have only one production server and we are hard coded parameter [server_name].

Now we have multiple production servers we need to run the same stored procedure across all the database, Is there any other way without using IF condition in SQL?

Please help me to do that.Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add some more description on what exactly you are doing, e.g. where do you use the servername? It's hard to tell if you only need a [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/cursors-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Why would your server_name be hard-coded on your stored procedure ?. Can you show a bit of code about how you call that stored procedure ?.

Answer (score 0):

Best practise would be to have one server link to the other servers. This would avoid having different stored procedures on differrent servers.

A single server with linked servers would simply require:

A different stored procedure for each specific server, tables referenced fully SERVER.DATABASE.DBO.TABLE

Then I would just setup a "master procedure" which simply calls each procedure in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below example:

```
CREATE TABLE server_db_link(server_id INT, Server_name VARCHAR(100), db_name varchar(100));

INSERT INTO server_db_link(server_id, server_name, db_name) 
VALUES(1, '[HOST1\INSTANCE1]', 'database1'),
(2, '[HOST1\INSTANCE2]', 'database2'),
(3, '[HOST2\INSTANCE3]', 'database3');


DECLARE @SQL_var NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @SQL_var = @SQL_var + 'EXEC '+server_name+'.'+db_name+'.dbo.procedure_name'
FROM server_db_link;

EXEC (@SQL_var);
```